# How to run cmd in admin mode in Automation Anywhere Workbench

Tags: automationanywhere

I want to stop a window service that is allowed only in admin mode:

```
net stop dsNcService
```

I have tried with action *Open Program/File* but it doesn't work. Is it possible to run *Open Program/File* in admin mode?

Answer (score 2):

For stopping services you can use, **Stop Service** command.

However, to run CMD as Admin change the settings in Automation Anywhere Client.

Tools --> Options --> Runtime Settings -> Tick Run task as Administrator

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That works but there is prompt from wins OS "**User Account Control** Do you want to allow the app to make changes to your device?"

Comment: The prompt can be turned off in wins settings.